# OpenLayers 6 get features of vector tiles within polygon

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I am trying to get all the features from VectorTile "ol/layer/VectorTile" which are within a drawn polygon using getFeaturesInExtent:

**Tile Layer**

```
const tileLyr = new VectorTileLayer({
  zIndex: 10,
  renderMode: "vector",
  source: new VectorTileSource({
    overlaps: false,
    format: new MVT({
      featureClass: Feature,
    }),
    tileSize: 4096,
    url,
  }),
});
map?.addLayer(tileLyr);
```

**Get Features in Extent**

```
const draw = new Draw({
  type: "Polygon",
  source: new VectorSource(),
});

map.addInteraction(draw);

draw.on("drawend", (e) => {
  let geom = e.feature.getGeometry();
  var format = new GeoJSON();
  var geojson1 = format.writeFeaturesObject([e.feature]);
  tileLyr
    ?.getSource()
    ?.getFeaturesInExtent(geom.getExtent(), function (features) {
      console.log(features);
    });
```

After drawing the polygon, its not logging any features. It seems its not going into the getFeaturesInExtent function.

Comment: `getFeaturesInExtent` does not use a callback,  `var features = tileLyr.getSource().getFeaturesInExtent(geom.getExtent()); console.log(features);` should work.

Comment: @Mike Tried that as well. Still getting empty array. https://antef-test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screenshot+from+2022-04-24+11-15-55.png

Comment: What is `tileLayer`? There is not enough relevant code included in the question to pinpoint what goes wrong. Please edit your question and add all code relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Mike I have updated the question, please check. Also, tileLyr.getFeatures(event.pixel, function(f)=>{}) and map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(f)=>{}) are working perfectly fine

Comment: Your code works for me with a standard 512 size tile source https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-4yq5hq?file=/main.js  (it is quite slow with `featureClass: Feature`) so maybe the problem is related to your source?

Comment: @MIke Found the issue. I am using useGeographic(). As my features are in 4326. I removed the useGeographic and it worked as expected. Is there any way, to fix this as i need to call useGeographic

Comment: Coordinates in vector tiles will be treated as if they are in the view projection.  What do you get from `console.log(geom.getExtent())`? (maybe something much smaller than you expected)