# Get all info feature of layers within polygon from another layer

Tags: polygon, openlayers, getfeatureinfo

I found [this example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-4yq5hq?file=/main.js)  - [(question details for example)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429619/openlayers-6-get-features-of-vector-tiles-within-polygon). It allows to get all the features in the drawn polygon. It's almost what i needed, but instead of drawing, I want when clicking on the `feature` of the upper layer(layerA) to get all the `feature info` of `layer B` within polygon of `layerA`.

Here is two layers that I have:

**Layer A**

```
var layerA = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://xxxxxxx/geoserver/xxx/wms',
        params: {LAYERS: 'xxx:xxxa', 'TILED':true, 'format':'image/png8'},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        ratio: 1,
    }),
    minZoom: 10,
    visible: true,
})
map.addLayer(layerA);
```

**Layer B**

```
var layerB = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://xxxxxxx/geoserver/xxx/wms',
        params: {LAYERS: 'xxx:xxxb', 'TILED':true, 'format':'image/png8'},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        ratio: 1,
    }),
    minZoom: 10,
    visible: true,
})
map.addLayer(layerB);
```

By this way I can get `feature info` but only at click position:

```
function showInfo(coord, resol) {
  var content = document.getElementById('info');
  var url = layerA.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
    coord,
    resol,
    'EPSG:3857',
    {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName':'name,id'
    },
  );
  if(url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var feature = data.features[0];
      var props = feature.properties;
      content.innerHTML = '<h5>name : </h5><p>' + props.name + '</p>' + ...
    });
    }
  else {
    content.innerHTML = ''
  }
}

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  showInfo(evt.coordinate, map.getView().getResolution());
})
```

Comment: The example you are citing does not give all the feature within drawn polygon, but all the features within bounding box of drawn polygon.

Comment: As you say. But it's almost like what i wanted. Instead of all the features within bounding box, I want to get all `info feature` of `layerB` within polygon of `feature` from `layerA`.

Comment: The example you are citing deals with vector layer. You can't achieve what you want with WMS layer, since here you can only get feature info for specified point.

Comment: Is it possible to use `getFeaturesAtCoordinate` or `getFeaturesInExtent`? I can only use WMS because the layer data is so large. Or some way I can achieve what I want

Comment: `getFeatureInfoUrl` with CQL filter (using operator `INTERSECTS`) might work, but that's not my area of knowledge, so I can't help you here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, it was very helpful to me. I will learn more about them. I spent a lot of time researching this question, hope to get good results. Thank, again. Sir!